# using python to play audio using remote desktop

Tags: sound, python

I am using pyaudio to play a tone. I am using the example that taneli gave here [LINK](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202355/how-to-play-a-fixed-frequency-sound-using-python)

I am using a WinXP computer to log into a ubuntu computer using remote desktop. When I have the ubuntu computer logged in with user_x and I also remote into the ubuntu computer (from the WinXP computer) with user_x, I can hear the audio from the ubuntu computer's speakers (whether or not I set remote desktop to transfer sound to the WinXP computer or not).

If I log into the ubuntu computer with user_y and I remote into the ubuntu computer (from the WinXP computer) with user_x, I cannot hear the audio from the ubuntu computer's speakers.

What I would prefer is for the sound to be transferred to WinXP computer, but will settle for the sound to play on the Ubuntu computer regardless of the usernames.

I'm don't know if this is enough information to provide an answer, but I'm not sure what else to add.

thanks
Steve